# How to Change page Title of Magento Module?

Tags: magento

I have successfully install magento, but site title remain magento, I try many times but did not change that title?and did not change thing under the widget?  so what is the procedures?

Comment: Have you entered your store name in System -> Configuration -> General -> Store Information -> Store Name?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can do it via layout files:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Your Title</title></action>
</reference>
```

or via code by accessing head block element and calling `setTitle('your title')`  method on it

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('your title');
```

grep for more references:

```
grep '>setTitle(' app/code/ -rsn
```

Comment: I did exactly this but I'm still not able to add a custom title using `setTitle()` inside the module's layout XML file. Is there something that you have to register in the index controller in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Put this function in Block page of that Module

```
public function _prepareLayout()  
{  
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Your Page Title'));  
    return parent::_prepareLayout();  
}
```