# Category and product name standard included in the page title

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to name the category and product standard to be included in the TITLE of the page? Now only the default title is displayed.

For example the title of a product in the category 'XXX' must have the automatic page title: PRODUCT NAME | XXX | Default title.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544660/how-to-change-page-title-of-magento-module, http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/change-any-page-title-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to change the title of page,just look for View.php file in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product folder and find `function _prepareLayout()` in this function you can see the title variable and change the title anything you want.

Comment: I guess he wants to change the title dynamically.

Comment: yes from here you can give title dynamically because from this function you can get category name and product name and give them as a title

Comment: @mufaddal, I'll +1 your answer if you also provide the code that can retrieve current category and product names... because we could then override it in app/code/local, yes??

Comment: to retrieve current category and product name code is there in prepare layout() function.